# Problem with saving foreign key with @OneToOne annotation. Saving as null

Tags: java, one-to-one, quarkus, jpa-annotations

I have two entities (`Project`, `OtherData`) with one abstract entity. I'm using MySQL and Quarkus framework.

**Problem:** When I try to save `Project` entity field `project_id` remains `null`.

Table schemas:

[image: table "projects"]
[image: table "project_other_data"]

On next picture there is shown, fk constraint in "project_other_data" table:
[image]

**Abstract Entity**:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long id;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**Project Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Project extends AbstractEntity {

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "date_create")
    @JsonbDateFormat(value = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate dateCreate;

    @Column(name = "date_update")
    @JsonbDateFormat(value = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate dateUpdate;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "project", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private OtherData otherData;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**OtherData Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project_other_data")
public class OtherData extends AbstractEntity {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    private Project project;

    @Column(name = "days_in_year")
    private Integer daysInYear;

    @Column(name = "holidays_in_year")
    private Integer holidaysInYear;

    @Column(name = "weeks_in_year")
    private Integer weeksInYear;

    @Column(name = "free_saturdays")
    private Integer freeSaturdays;

    @Column(name = "downtime_coefficient")
    private BigDecimal downtimeCoefficient;

    @Column(name = "changes")
    private Integer changes;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Saving entities with code:

```
@Path("projects")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ProjectRest {

    @Inject
    ProjectService projectService;

    @POST
    public Response saveProject(Project project) {
        return Response.ok(projectService.saveProject(project)).build();
    }
}
```

```
@RequestScoped
@Transactional
public class ProjectService {

    @Inject
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public Project saveProject(Project project) {

        if (project.getId() == null) {
            entityManager.persist(project);
        } else {
            entityManager.merge(project);
        }

        return project;
    }
}
```

Comment: You showed the `Project` class a second time instead of the `OtherData` class. Please add the code for the `OtherData` class.

Comment: @Turing85, oh, sorry. Didn't notice that. I've just edited it.

Comment: Can you modify `@JoinColumn(name = "project_id")` to `@JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName="id")`?

Comment: Also, do you generate the table schemas automatically or manually? It seems that you are missing a foreign key constraint on table `project_other_data.project_id`.

Comment: Turing85, yes. it didn't help.

Comment: I generated it manually

Comment: Can you provide a link to the project, e.g. on github?

Comment: Turing85, It have fk constraint, I added a table scene screenshot in question.

Comment: Turing85, here is link to GitHub project: https://github.com/cat-inGlasses/org_prod

Comment: @act_inGlasses No need to edit the title after accepting an answer, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question 
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the problem by `POST`ing a new `Project` with an embedded `OtherData`. The body I used for the `POST`:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "surname": "Doe",
    "otherData": {}
}
```

Point is: the database entity is also used as DTO. Thus, the field `project` in `otherData` for the request body is set to `null` (since no `Project` is passed along this would be a recursive infinite definition).

During processing the entity from the rest controller to the service to the repository, the `project` of `otherData` is never set. A quick fix is to modify `ProjectService::saveProject` as follows:

```
public Project saveProject(Project project) {
    project.getOtherData().setProject(project); // This line was added
    if (project.getId() == null) {
        entityManager.persist(project);
    } else {
        entityManager.merge(project);
    }

    return project;
}
```

This will fix the database issue (the `project_id` will be set), but leads to the next issue. The response body cannot be serialized due to an

> org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY008205: JSON Binding serialization error javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Unable to serialize property 'otherData' from com.nikitap.org_prod.entities.Project
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Recursive reference has been found in class class com.nikitap.org_prod.entities.Project.

The object structure is cyclic (`project` references `otherData`, which return references `project`, ...) and Jackson is unable to resolve this cycle.

To fix this issue, I would suggest to separate DTOs and database entity and explicitly map between them. In essence:

- Structure the Dto-object to represent the JSON-Request and -Response you expect to receive, in a non-cyclic order
- Transfer JSON-related annotations from the database entity classes to the DTO classes
- In the service- or repository-layer (your choice), map the DTO to the database entites, setting all fields (including the references from `project` to `otherData` and vice-versa)
- In the same layer, map database-entites back to non-cyclic DTOs
- Return the DTOs from the REST endpoint